# Change Table format to Div

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo UI Grid plugin. How can I Change Grid Table layout to Div based layout?

And also I am able to Create New / Edit existing item etc...

Please check the below reference image for more clarification...

Any help please?

> **[Online Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ehuCU)**

[image: Kendo Grid]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/api">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />

    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <div id="grid"></div>

  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        columns: [
          { field: "Name" },
          { field: "Age" },
          { command: "edit" }
        ],
        dataSource: {
          data: [
            { id: 1, Name: "Reddy Prasad", Age: 30 },
            { id: 2, Name: "Gaurav Kapadia", Age: 33 }
          ],
          schema: {
            model: { id: "id" }
          }
        },
        editable: {
          mode: "popup",
          window: {
            title :"This is the title"
          }
        },
        toolbar: [{ name: 'create', text: 'Add' }]
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would require some styling to allow multiple `div`s per line and make it look the way you want, but using [kendo templates](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/rowtemplate), you can achieve this. Some CSS can be used for hiding the header and the row table can give that panel appearance to each item in a cell.

In the JavaScript there's a line for the row template and in the HTML, that template is defined and uses the fields from your `dataSource`.

*Please note* that the `data-uid="#: uid #"` on the `<tr>` in the template is *necessary* for the edit button to work. Without that property the button will be broken since it's not sure which "row" we want to edit.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        columns: [
          { field: "Name" },
          { field: "Age" },
          { command: "edit" }
        ],
        dataSource: {
          data: [
            { id: 1, Name: "Reddy Prasad", Age: 30 },
            { id: 2, Name: "Gaurav Kapadia", Age: 33 }
          ],
          schema: {
            model: { id: "id", Name: "", Age: "" }
          }
        },
        editable: {
          mode: "popup",
          window: {
            title :"This is the title"
          }
        },
        toolbar: [{ name: 'create', text: 'Add' }],
        rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#rowtemplate").html())
      });
    });
```

```css
html { 
    font-size: 14px; 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
}

.k-grid-header-wrap th {
    display: none;
}

tr {
    float: left;
}

.rowEdit {
    float: right;
}

.myPanel {
    border: 1px solid #888;
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 15px;
}

.myPanel label {
    clear: both; /* puts labels on new line */
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 0 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/api">
    <style></style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <div id="grid"></div>
    
 <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="rowtemplate">
 
   <tr data-uid="#: uid #"><td>
   
   <div class="myPanel">
   
     <a class="rowEdit k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-edit" href="\#">
       <span class="k-icon k-edit"></span>Edit
     </a>
   
     <label>Name: "#: Name #"</label>
     
     <label>Age: "#: Age #"</label>
   
  </div> 
  
  </td></tr>
 
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **@JB_**... Thanks for the reply... but **+ Add ** functionality is not working... getting error as "**Uncaught ReferenceError: Name is not defined**"

Comment: @Reddy, Sorry about that. You need to add those fields to the schema in your data source. I've updated the post to include this.

Comment: **@JB_** Thanks again... Working as expected... But small clarification, can I able to hide table tags / elements... Eg: Structure should be ::

    `<!-- Main Wrapper -->
    <div class="main-wrapper">
    
      <!-- Box -->
      <div class="box">
    
        <a class="rowEdit k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-edit" href="\#">
           <span class="k-icon k-edit"></span>Edit
        </a>
    
        <label>Name: "#: Name #"</label>
         
        <label>Age: "#: Age #"</label>
    
      </div>
      <!-- /Box -->
    
    </div>
    <!-- /Main Wrapper -->`

Comment: If your requirement isn't a table, you can always try using a **[ListView](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/listview/index)**. I've actually used it before to build a panel style layout and it's much easier to work with in my opinion for what you're looking for.

Comment: **@JB_**... Thanks for the TIP... I will definitely try that... I am **Accepting** and **Upvoting**  for your your smart answer...